# Delete every row that doesn't contain a blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

I need to delete every row in Excel that does **not** contain a "blank" value in one of its six columns.

I tried sorting each column, but there's 100k+ rows and that method really only works if I'm trying to sort by one column at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert a helper column, where you check number of blank cells.

For example, if you need to check columns A - F, and G is an empty column, then enter in G1:
`=COUNTA(A1:F1)`
Now you have just to sort by column G, and delete rows with `0`.